# Save localstorage data to server using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, local-storage

I'm trying to implement a "save later" functionality in jquery using localstorage. the idea is saving every form event in localstorage and using a button to sync them and save to the server.

I manage to save form data to localstorage and retrieve all the localstorage saved. Currently i'm struggling on how i can be able to submit specific values only to the server using PHP

Here's my code for saving form data to localstorage

```
$('#systemInventory').on("submit", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent the form from attempting to send to the web server
        let $inputs = $('#systemInventory :input');

        let values = {};
        $inputs.each(function() {
            values[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();
        });

        let title = 'systemInventory' + $.now();
        localStorage.setItem(title, JSON.stringify(values));
        $('#systemInventory')[0].reset();
        mdtoast('Successfully Saved',
            { type: mdtoast.INFO });
    });
```

and here's the one i used for retrieving data from the localstorage

```
function allStorage() {

    let values = [],
        keys = Object.keys(localStorage),
        i = keys.length;

    while ( i-- ) {
        values.push( localStorage.getItem(keys[i]) );
    }

    return values;
}
```

Here's the one i'm trying to do to save specific data in the PHP storage

```
$.each(allStorage(), function (key, value) {
        let data = JSON.parse(value);
        console.log(data);
        $.ajax({
            url: "sync.php",
            method: 'POST',
            data: {data: data},
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    });
```

and my php code is

```
if (isset($_POST['data'])){

    foreach ($_POST['data'] as $key => $value){

        $data[] = array(
            $key => $value
        );

    }

    $dataForm = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $data);

    print_r($dataForm);


//    print_r($data);

}
```

When console logging all the localstorage saved i have this result
[image]

and when clicking the sync, the one that is sending on the server i'm having this issue
[image]

what i really want to happen is when i submit the localstorage data to php it will automatically form specific array for example

```
$data = array(
'type'=>'product',
'beginning'=>1,
'delivery'=>1

);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `allStorage()` function is returning an indexed array, not an object, so you're getting only the values from local storage, not the keys too.

This means when you come to pass the data to PHP, it's ending up as an indexed, not associative, array, i.e. without keys. This would be apparent if you ran `print_r()` on the received data, for example.

`allStorage()` can be fixed (and simplified) as:

```
function allStorage() {
    let data = {}; //<-- note object, not array
    for (var key in localStorage) data[key] = localStrage[key];
    return data;
}
```

Comment: It looks like the each loop is also not needed, currently it makes multiple ajax calls.

Comment: so i will modify my allstorage to look like this? what would be its return value?

Comment: is it possible to get specific data only? because i'm returning unnecessary data  like i only want to return the object that contains ```storedata: {}```

Comment: ```productInventory1559037527236: "{"type":"Product","username":"","storeBookingSchedId":"","product_id":"1374","beginning":"1","delivery":"1","ending":"1","offtake":"1","average_offtake":"0.14","days_stock_level":"7.00","add":""}"```
Something like this one

Comment: Well without digging deeper into your project I don't know. I've answered the specific question that was ask. If you have further issues re: how to extract certain data, or parse it ready for sending, I would post a separate question.

Comment: ``` Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

i'm receiving this whenever i'm trying to use the code you sent

Comment: It's not from the code I posted. You don't mention the line the error is coming from.